# Why is my crontab -e not running my python script?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, cron

I want to run hello.py file which contains `print("Hello World")` using crontab.

For that, my hello.py has this code:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3
print('Hello, world!')
```

And, in the same folder, I have used crontab -e command to open crontab and in order to execute this file every minute, I have written:

```
1 * * * * ./hello.py
```

I have also set permissions for the file to be executable using `chmod a+x hello.py`.

When I run

> `/usr/bin/python3 hello.py`

It runs perfectly. Also, when I use only `./hello.py`, the file runs.

Why is it still not executed using crontab?

Comment: Try to redirect its output in some file, and then check if its printing in it or not. I don't know how you are checking its running status, if not this. You can do this by ./hello.py >> test.log
 Edit : Also mention the full path in crontab of hello.py

Comment: Forgot to mention, 1 * * * * will not execute it every minute but every hour at 1 min i.e. *:01 hrs. * * * * * is what you need.

Comment: Hi, my crontab -e started running. What I did was I rebooted the system. And checked for test.log. It was created in /home folder of my OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nailed it!

Instead of using `1 * * * * ./hello.py` in crontab to set the cron running per minute , I rewrote the statement to `1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 hello.py` .

This solved the problem!